# return and use chained http promise from a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, promise

I need help with understanding HTTP promises chain.

I'm trying to have the following scenario:

```
public class Serv1 extends IServ1 {

    public HelpMe() : ng.IHttpPromise<any> {

            $http.post(something) -> function(somethingResult) {

                // I want to return this promise from this method and use it outside
                $http.get(somethingResult)
        }
    }
}
```

In my other service I want to use `Serv1.HelpMe` method:

```
public class Serv2 extends IServ2 {

    public UseHelpMePromise() {
        var scope = this;
        this.serv1.HelpMe() -> function(resultOfInnerHelpMePromise){    
            scope.doLogic(resultOfInnerHelpMePromise)
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me and tell me which keywords I should use instead of the '->' I used in my code above. 
Should I use `.then` or should it be `.success`?

Moreover, when should I put a return statement in the `HelpMe` method if I want to return the inner promise (The GET method promise)?

Lastly should I use `.catch` / `.error` or none of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it something like this:

```
public class Serv1 extends IServ1 {
    public HelpMe(): ng.IHttpPromise<any> {
        return $http.post(something).then(somethingResult => {
            return $http.get(somethingResult);
        });
    }
}

public class Serv2 extends IServ2 {
    public UseHelpMePromise() {
        this.serv1.HelpMe().then(resultOfInnerHelpMePromise => {
            this.doLogic(resultOfInnerHelpMePromise);
        });
    }
}
```